# Angular HttpClient ResponseTyp Error

Tags: angular, http, ionic-framework, httpclient

I try to download an image(png) from a api. My problem is, that for some reason only json files are accepted by ionic/angular.

```
return this.http.get(this.authKeys.serverURL, {headers: this.header, responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob});
```

Following error occurs:

```
 Argument of type '{ headers: any; responseType: ResponseContentType.Blob; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ headers?: HttpHeaders | { [header: string]: string | string[]; }; observe?: "body"; params?: Ht...'.   Types of property 'responseType' are incompatible.     Type 'ResponseContentType.Blob' is not assignable to type '"json"'.
```

For some reason only a response of type json is allowed...

Comment: Try this -[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319272/angular-5-httpclient-observe-and-responsetype-blob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49319272/angular-5-httpclient-observe-and-responsetype-blob)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[**`responseType`**](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#responseType) holds string value. So you should be passing either of these values

```
'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text';
```

In earlier version Angular 2, it API was designed to expect enum value for `responseType`, [check here](https://v2.angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/http/index/RequestOptionsArgs-interface.html#!#responseType-anchor)

Comment: I'm also getting the same error even when I use one of those four Strings. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 7):

For me, it worked with " as 'json' " syntax:

```
responseType: 'blob' as 'json'
```